# Dotted lists in Guile Scheme

Tags: scheme, guile

How can I specifically check for dotted-lists in the form `(a . b)` Guile? The `dotted-list` of srfi-1 strangely returns #t also for e.g. Numbers (since when are numbers Lists too? https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/SRFI_002d1-Predicates.html)! And `pair?` will evaluate to #t also for normal lists. Is there a way to differentiate the `(a . b)` construct from other things, whereas the `b` part (the cdr) could itself be any object including other association lists etc.?

This is what i didn't expect and can't understand:

```
(dotted-list? '(c . ((d . 3)
                     (e . 4)))) ; ===> #f

(dotted-list? 3) ; ===> #t
```

Comment: A pair whose `cdr` is a proper list is a proper list. The "dotted" version would be '(c . ((d . 3) . (e . 4))).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `(atom . (x1 ... xn))` is another way of writing `(atom x1 ... xn)`, so `(c . ((d . 3) (e . 4)))` is just equivalent to `(c (d . 3) (e . 4))` which is nothing more than a three element list (and for this reason `dotted-list?` returns false in this case).

If you don't like the definition of `dotted-list?` given in srf-1 then define your own version:

```
(define (my-dotted-list? l)
  (and (dotted-list? l)
       (pair? l)))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted a standalone definition (one that doesn't depend on an existing definition which you don't agree with), then I think this is reasonable:

```
(define (dotted-list? c)
  (and (cons? c)
       (cond [(cons? (cdr c))
              (dotted-list? (cdr c))]
             [(null? (cdr c))
              #f]
             [else #t])))
```

Note that like any simple-minded definition this fails to halt on circular lists.